# Neo4j core: Load RelationShips with order

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to develop and application that require millions of relationships. But when trying to get the last relations using cypher query or core java (parse all relations) based on creation time (timestamp) it takes a lot of time.

Generally, users will access data starting from the last ones to the first ones and may need only to the last 50 one. So I How can I change the behavior of Neo4j when loading data in order to start from the last ones (even for data in cache) so I will not need to reorder them.

Regards.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your graph model?

Comment: the graph is like this: User<-friend->User, User-creates->Event, User-follows->Event. every user can check the list of events he follows from the newest to the oldest one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give every node a `timestamp` property with its creation time (which can be obtained using the Cypher `timestamp()` function).

Then, you can match the last 50 created using this subquery (which can be placed before your actual query):

```
MATCH (n)
ORDER BY n.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 50
WITH n
// Place your actual query here. The variable 'n' will be a collection of the last 50 nodes created.
```

Unfortunately, this will not be very quick, since neo4j will iterate through every node to find the ones with the highest `timestamp` value. If you only need certain nodes to have the timestamp, you should consider adding a label (say, 'Timestamped') to all of those nodes and change `MATCH (n)` to `MATCH (n:Timestamped)`.

Comment: thank you for your responses, I used the node identifier as reference istead of timestamp but it's still slow.

Comment: Yes, that is no surprising. It is too bad that neo4j does not (yet) support using an index to speed up `ORDER BY` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time on your event-nodes, you can put them in a time tree, see here:

In the Java API you can use legacy indexes for the nodes or relationships, indexing the timestamp as an numeric value and then use a lucene range query.

It looks something like this:

```
Index<Node> timeIndex = db.index().forNodes("time");

timeIndex.add(node,"timestamp",ValueContext.indexNumeric(node.getProperty("timestamp"));

timeIndex.query(QueryContext.numericRange("timestamp",from,to));
```

See the [QueryContext API](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.4.M06/apidocs/org/neo4j/index/lucene/QueryContext.html#numericRange%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Number,%20java.lang.Number%29)